# No internet connection in android app

Tags: java, android, ocr

I'm using mezzofanti OCR open source,
and I'm trying to download a language,
but it says that I have no internet connection,
the internet connection on my device is open and working,
I have internet permission on my android manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

so I don't understand why isn't it working ?

this is the log cat :

```
10-10 18:10:27.925: V/MLOG: Download.java:(12289): DownloadFile opened connection
10-10 18:10:27.930: V/MLOG: Download.java:(12289): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/tessdata/temp/languages.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-10 18:10:27.970: D/dalvikvm(12289): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 94K, 3% free 10046K/10311K, paused 19ms
10-10 18:10:27.990: V/MLOG: OCR.java:(12289): GetLanguage(): eng
10-10 18:10:28.115: W/SurfaceView(12289): CHECK surface infomation creating=false formatChanged=false sizeChanged=false visible=false visibleChanged=true surfaceChanged=true realSizeChanged=false redrawNeeded=false left=false top=false
10-10 18:11:04.680: V/MLOG: Download.java:(12289): DownloadLanguageBrief (http://www.itwizard.ro/mezzolang/languages.txt)
10-10 18:11:05.005: V/MLOG: Download.java:(12289): DownloadFile opened connection
10-10 18:11:05.010: V/MLOG: Download.java:(12289): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/tessdata/temp/languages.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-10 18:11:05.080: V/MLOG: OCR.java:(12289): GetLanguage(): eng
10-10 18:11:05.100: D/dalvikvm(12289): GC_CONCURRENT freed 566K, 7% free 9897K/10567K, paused 7ms+3ms
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289): Activity com.itwizard.mezzofanti.PreferencesActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4167e4a0 that was originally added here
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.itwizard.mezzofanti.PreferencesActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4167e4a0 that was originally added here
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:386)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at com.itwizard.mezzofanti.PreferencesActivity.ShowAlert(PreferencesActivity.java:229)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at com.itwizard.mezzofanti.PreferencesActivity.CreateDownloadableLangsSubMenu(PreferencesActivity.java:342)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at com.itwizard.mezzofanti.PreferencesActivity.onCreate(PreferencesActivity.java:195)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3363)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:127)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1163)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
10-10 18:15:07.385: E/WindowManager(12289):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 18:15:07.440: V/MLOG: Download.java:(12289): DownloadLanguageBrief (http://www.itwizard.ro/mezzolang/languages.txt)
10-10 18:15:08.120: V/MLOG: Download.java:(12289): DownloadFile opened connection
10-10 18:15:08.120: V/MLOG: Download.java:(12289): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/tessdata/temp/languages.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-10 18:15:08.185: V/MLOG: OCR.java:(12289): GetLanguage(): eng
10-10 18:15:11.375: D/dalvikvm(12289): GC_CONCURRENT freed 173K, 5% free 10128K/10567K, paused 3ms+5ms
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error message isn't telling you that you don't have internet, it is telling you that the given file cannot be found. You will have to verify that the file exists.

Comment: The file name in the error is `http://www.itwizard.ro/mezzolang/languages.txtlanguages.txt`. You should probably drop the last part where `languages.txt` is doubled. The fixed URL works in my browser, at least.

Comment: the error message i get on my samsung says that I don't have internet connection. the file http://www.itwizard.ro/mezzolang/languages.txtlanguages.txt do exist, I've checked. I think that it says that it don't exist because of the internet connection problem...

Comment: @MickeyHaim, I just tried your link. Big 404. Your URL is incorrect. If you remove the second languages.txt it works (I just tried). Further, your stack trace says nothing about a faulty internet connect. If anything it affirms that you have one.

Comment: yes you are right the file with the extra "languages.txt" doesn't exist, that is just one of my attempts to fix the problem. but when I corrected the file name to http://www.itwizard.ro/mezzolang/languages.txt, the problem still occurs, I've edited the log cat.

Comment: @MickeyHaim Now the file that you are saving to, the one on the SDcard, its file path is incorrect. Or you haven't created the file. Either way, that needs to be fixed. The error has nothing to do with your internet connection.